# How connect to multiple mikrotik at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mikrotik, router-os

I can't figure out how to create more than one api connection to microtics (I have more than 20 of them) using [routeros-client](https://github.com/aluisiora/routeros-client) at the same time.
Is it possible to somehow connect a config with parameters and credentials? I will be glad to any advice and tips

```
const RouterOSClient = require('routeros-client').RouterOSClient;

const api = new RouterOSClient({
host: '',
user: '',
password: '',
})
```

Comment: I see there are no answers, so I want to recommend you to try to implement the necessary functionality on Python, multithreading is relatively easy to do there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved in such way:
Firstly there was created config.yml, then defined variables and use forEach() method.

```
const yaml_config = require('node-yaml-config');
const config = yaml_config.load(__dirname + '/config/host.yml');
```